# warning when compiling perl module PNI-Node-Tk-0.14

Tags: perl, mingw32, dmake

i get this warning when i make Perl module [`PNI-Node-Tk-0.14`](https://metacpan.org/release/FIBO/PNI-Node-Tk-0.14):

```
Warning: NAME must be a package name
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for PNI-Node-Tk
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers don't like - in names

Comment: @StromRideR: I still do not understand :) ?